# .empty() clears the event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm targetting `js-trigger-restoreb` that exist in a div with class `b_edit_meta`, example:

```
<div class="b_edit_meta">
   <div class="js-trigger-restoreb">Click</div>
</div>
```

Whenever I have the following line in my code:

```
jQuery(this).closest("li").find(".b_edit_meta").empty();
```

It stops the rest of the function to work, probably because `.empty()` is clearing it.

Is there any way to empty that div without clearing the event?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.js-trigger-restoreb').bind("mouseup", function() {

        jQuery(this).closest("li").find(".b_edit_meta").empty();

        // because of above line, nothing else works here

    });
});
```

Test the full code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txkqfd3h/).

Comment: Why not use `.html('')`?

Comment: @hmd See updated question.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson There's no `li` there. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: You're traversing up the DOM, then removing stuff, including the element you're working with.  The next `jQuery(this)` isn't going to find anything because `empty()` removed it.  It's not really clear what you're end goal is though...

Comment: @JamesThorpe are you sure about that? https://jsfiddle.net/txkqfd3h/1/ . OP needs to include his HTML in the fiddle

Comment: @NachoDawg Ok, so `$(this)` is fine, but try doing the `closest('li')` as per OP - that won't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `this` after that `.empty()` in any other way than to refer to `jQuery(this).closest("li")...` and then something.

Try to just save that refrence to the `li` before emptying your container

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.js-trigger-restoreb').bind("mouseup", function() {

        var closestLi = $(this).closest("li");

        // find the edit bullet content and remove the meta stuff
        $(closestLi).find(".b_edit_meta").empty();
```

then keep using `closestLi` instead of referencing to "this" which doesn't exist anymore after you emptied `this`'s container

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery documentation on [.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event handlers (so they can be re-added later), use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead.